# Read CSV file from FTP and update records in salesforce

Tags: data-loader, field-update, ftp

I want to read a csv file from SFTP server and using that i need to update records or mark checkbox field true in Salesforce. This needs to be scheduled to run everyday. Can you please suggest a better approach for this? Don't want to use informatica cloud/ Jitterbit Data Loader.

Few method i thinked use Command line data loader inside FTP server to push the data into salesforce?

Comment: Perhaps you can schedule an apex class to fetch the csv file and process it for you?

Comment: Thanks.@Kasper  File is on FTP update every day need a automatic scenario read file on FTP update records in Salesforce.....

Answer (score 2):

You can't access files(either upload or download) from FTP in Apex Code or other from Salesforce.

Your best bet would be to use an external application. CastIron, Dell Boomi is the go to application for FTP interactions with salesforce.

Also you can create your own webservice outside of the salesforce platform and call it from Apex.